# All reputation is gone

Tags: support, reputation, user-accounts, merge-accounts

I am sorry to post here but Cross Validated did a merge on my account and I lost all reputation points on my stats forum and I cannot post to meta without any reputation points. I don't know what this merge means.

How do I solve this problem or where to address this question?

Comment: Could you explain what happened? Your account is [still live](http://stats.stackexchange.com/users/20980/cagdas-ozgenc), AFAICT. Did you create a brand new account, or have you lost your login credentials? In this case, you should rather [contact the SE team](http://stats.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts).

Comment: I recently enrolled to quant forum. I tried my existing email thinking that it will login, but instead I think it created a separate account. Then all of a sudden today those credentials merged and my cross validated reputations disappeared. I always used the same e-mail. I think quant forum did not accept my e-mail due to the fact that it was beta.

Comment: http://meta.stats.stackexchange.com/users/54842/cagdas-ozgenc

Comment: http://stats.stackexchange.com/users/20980/cagdas-ozgenc

Comment: I think these are two separate users with same e-mail and password and I cannot login to the one with the reputations anymore. If necessary we can destroy the one with no reputation in cross validated.

Comment: Unless I am mistaken, these two accounts point to the same user but registration may have been done using a different email address. If that is the case, please follow the instructions that I provided above. I would recommend to contact the SE team to see what's more appropriate (merging/deleting) because you are not using the same account on stats.SE and quant.SE, and thus cannot link both accounts (which would get you 100 points of reputation, BTW).

Comment: Follow the instructions [here](http://stats.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts) and we can get these accounts merged for you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The analysis of the situation revealed that I accidentally set up two accounts one for CrossValidated and one for Quant forum.

Then the Quant login propagated to CrossValidated automatically as a convenience provided by the system. As a result I thought all my reputation was lost. In reality it was still on the other account.

Thanks to admins they merged my accounts by following the steps in the comments above.

All is good now.

Comment: Thank you for posting a summary of what happened and of the resolution of the problem.